# Downloaded facebook information shows numbers instead of names in chat history

Tags: html, facebook

I downloaded my entire facebook information and want to use my chat history saved in `messenger.htm`. The problem is that randomly names are shown as '1751624452@facebook.com':

```
...
<div class="message_header"><span class="user">100000849294497&#064;facebook.com</span><span class="meta">Montag, 6. Februar 2017 um 23:08 UTC+01</span></div>
               </div>
               <p>Hello</p>
....
```

How can I get the name of the person who send the message only knowing this number?

I changed the numbers randomly to keep everything anonym, in case those numbers represent something.

Comment: If Facebook wanted you to have those names, they would probably have included them in the first place. This might be users that have deleted their account in the meantime, or something like that. You could of course try and see if those numbers are indeed just global user ids, so that basic info about them could be requested via API; but since Facebook has made an effort to introduce more privacy in that regard by introducing app-scoped user ids, I rather doubt that will work.

Comment: I looked up the chat and those user id's sometimes even refer to myself. I understand the privacy aspect, but why would they refer to my own name as an anonymous id?